How many requests are performed in bucket.objects.all() in boto3?
I'm using boto3 to scan my entire bucket, with the aim to know which files are older than a certain time threshold.
As a first approach, I've used
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.objects.all()

But I'm wondering if this counts as 1 request or as 1 request per 1000 objects, since I have more than 1 million files in my bucket and I don't want this script to cost me a few bucks every time it is executed.
I have also some folders that I do not want to scan, so I don't know if this is the best approach to do it.

The code shown will only ever make one API call.  If, however, you enumerate the objects in the .all() result set, you will need to make at least one call per 1000 items, since the underlying REST API has no mechanism to return more objects per call.

With 1 million objects in a bucket, it is a good idea to avoid listing the bucket. Alternatives are to keep your own listing in a database, or use Amazon S3 Inventory, which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.
